# Inlining a php script in a form's action attribute

Tags: php, html, forms

Why does this not work?

```
<form action="<?php echo 'test'; ?>"><input type="submit"></form>
```

Why is it that to echo 'test', I would need to place the PHP into a separate file, and point the action attribute to it? If I have multiple forms with short PHP scripts, can I not simply inline them somehow to carry out tasks, instead of making many external files to do so?

My intention is to have a sort of control panel to make different types of changes to a database.

Comment: How about explaining WHY this is a bad question instead of downvoting? No duplicate question, example code provided, what more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place **code** in the action attribute, that's simply not how HTML works.

```
<form action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="dotest">
```

You will need a *router* in your application that dispatches the tasks. In this case the "do" query parameter will dictate what to do. The code can be a big switch statement (not recommended), or you can store the actions in separate files/classes/class methods. You can look up the code directly (`file_exists`/`method_exists`/autoloading...) or you can decouple the lookup and do some kind of pre-registration and store the actions in a dictionary(`array`).

I would recommend checking some PHP frameworks too get some ideas. There are some very clever routers and controller abstractions out there. It's going to be better than you can come up with, especially if you're unexperienced.

Note: there's nothing wrong with lots of small files - just try to use a single entry point for your web application.

Comment: I don't have an external file. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want 10 files that are only 3 or 4 lines long, if I can place them in the same file as the form(s)

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser does not and cannot care about PHP. When the browser receives this HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo 'test'; ?>"><input type="submit"></form>
```

What is it supposed to do with that? Just "run the PHP"? You mean the PHP that is set up and configured *on your server*? No, that's simply not how it works.

The HTML specification says the `action` attribute points to a *URL* which the browser will send the form data to. It is then completely up to the server at that URL to do something with it, and that's where PHP runs.

You don't need to have separate physical files either, you can submit all forms to the same PHP file/URL, which then figures out what it received and outputs different things depending on that. You're also possibly wanting to look into Javascript and AJAX requests.

Comment: So is there an alternative to making multiple PHP files? Can I place the PHP in the same file at the top of the page and then get the action to point back to the same page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Nobody said it needs to be separate files. It just needs to be a URL, and the server can respond with anything it wants to. It can even be the URL the form is at.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, then.